# What does Islam say when the husband barely provides for the expenditure and expects the wife to take the financial burden?

Tags: sharia, finance, muslim-practices, family

I earn more than my husband. My husband's family is needy too. He send half of his earning to his family. But I am the person responsible for house, bills, food etc important for life. He pays sometimes if he wish. I do not like it anymore. I do not know how to talk with him about this. He even never wish to take any responsibility. We are newly married. But I do not like it this way. My family also wants me to send them something. But as I spend for all, I can not save anything for them. When I try to talk, he says this is both of our money. But it looks like my money is only his, his money is not for me.

What Islam says about this?

Comment: perhaps this book help you: http://www.al-islam.org/rights-women-islam-ayatullah-murtadha-mutahhari

Answer (score 2):

According to (4:32):

> وَلاَ تَتَمَنَّوْاْ مَا فَضَّلَ اللّهُ بِهِ بَعْضَكُمْ عَلَى بَعْضٍ
>   لِّلرِّجَالِ نَصِيبٌ مِّمَّا اكْتَسَبُواْ وَلِلنِّسَاء نَصِيبٌ مِّمَّا
>   اكْتَسَبْنَ وَاسْأَلُواْ اللّهَ مِن فَضْلِهِ إِنَّ اللّهَ كَانَ
>   بِكُلِّ شَيْءٍ عَلِيمًا
>
> "And do not wish for that by which Allah has made some of you exceed
>   others. For men is a share of what they have earned, and for women is
>   a share of what they have earned. And ask Allah of his bounty. Indeed
>   Allah is ever, of all things, Knowing."

Men and women are owner of their property, and can spend them in different allowable (mobah) ways.
Woman can spend her money without husband’s permission, although it’s better to do so.
And man should pay alimony to his wife and with the exception of that, he could spend his money in other ways, he wants.
However it’s better to have consultation with each other.